# Shutdown hook how to distinguish normal and abrupt(by user) shutdown

Tags: java, shutdown-hook

In my application i have added a shutdown hook for some clean up and finishing last transaction. As all docs stated this hook is also called on "normal" shutdown - if all is finished.

But i want to give the user some feedback:

> "ctrl-c detected - trying to finish..."

This feedback i only want to give on "abrupt" shut down.

So is there a way to detect the kind of shutdown in shutdown hook?

Answer (score 0):

As I considered that subject earlier, `Ctrl-C` is normal shutdown event (like `kill -15 <pid>` in Linux). Therefore, your shutdown hook should work.

From javadoc (for `Runtime.addShutdownHook()`):
"

> The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of
>   events:
>
> The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or
>   when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
>
> The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt,
>   such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or
>   system shutdown.

".

But also there is an uncaught shutdown (like `kill -9 <pid>` in Linux), this case no way to catch and handle it. Process (JVM) would be killed on OS level and no signal would be generated for application.

Comment: i edited the title of my question: i need to distinguish if the user initiated the shutdown.